# Are you mandated to use a Fault isolation manual when clearing a defect on an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, dash-8

I operate a Bombardier Dash 8 Q400. I want to know if aircraft engineers are mandated to close or rectify a defect by only following the fault isolation manual (FIM). Can an engineer instead use his knowledge and experience of the systems to isolate the problem and resolve the defect?

Comment: what are FIM and AMM?

Comment: As a pilot or maintenance?

Comment: @ Manu H Fault Isolation Manual and Aircraft Maintenance Manual

Comment: It would seem to depend on the particular aircraft, and perhaps whether it's private or commercial.  AFAIK there's no such thing as a "fault isolation manual" for my Piper Cherokee.

Comment: Engineer, or FAA certified mechanic?  Hypothetical, or actual situation?  If actual, and if properly diagnosed, I don't see a problem.  I could be wrong, but I don't think technicians are bound to using checklists in the way aircrew are.  Now if they didn't use a reference and missed something, that's a totally different issue.

Answer (score 1):

FIM contains procedures for both A/C systems (E.G. EICAS, ECAM, CPDS) messages and pilots/maitenance observations (e.g. smell of burning oil, windshield delamination).
All kind of reasonably possible faults should be covered by FIM.

**Just simply use yor FIM preambule to determine if it specifies what to do when fault is not covered by FIM** and to determine either mechanic judgement or OEM (A/C manufacturer)contact is requied in such case. 
If such information is not included contact OEM.